# tensorflow - tf.where TypeError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote the following test code (a part of a much bigger code)

```
import tensorflow as tf

update_boolean = [True, False, True, False, True, True]


with tf.Session() as sess:
    op = tf.where(update_boolean, lambda: tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1), lambda: tf.no_op())
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <function <lambda> at 0x000000000118E400>
```

how can I fix this?

what I want to do is create a list\tensor of operators (which are optimizer\do nothing) given a certain condition (not using `tf.cond` because i want to apply this to a batch so I have a list\tensor of booleans) 
* working in tensorflow 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1)` returns an Optimizer object, it is not clear how this relates to a no_op. I suggest starting by creating the optimizer and then conditioning on gradient updates instead, for instance by zeroing gradient contributions from the part of the batch wanted. `tf.where` does not work with operations, it provides indices for accessing tensors.

Comment: thanks. I understand. I thought this will allow to do a batch tf.cond, but it doesnt.